# how to make job run fast in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

We have one file of maximum size of 124 mb and remaining file less than that so when process the file in hive so do we need to change the block size if it is default 128mb if yes then how much and what will happen in doing so.

Comment: What is the size of other file. What is the block size of your hadoop cluster?

Comment: 10 mb 15 mb 30 mb .Block size is 134 mb

Comment: Answer can be found here. Please see my answer there- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222032/increase-number-of-hive-mappers-in-hadoop-2/30223107#30223107

Comment: so if we change the block size as 32 mb will it work instead of using set command

Comment: Don't do anything with block size leave is as it configured. Small file size is an overhead of hadoop cluster. Use input split in your code.You can set through below command `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` if you are using `YARN`.  Ideal block size should be 64 MB(medium data size) or 128 MB (for very large data size)

Comment: Actually I have tried by decreasing the block size so basically it will also do the same correct me if i'm wrong.